# Primefaces: Orderlist: index out of bound exception while reordering

Tags: primefaces, java-ee-6, indexoutofboundsexception

additionally to my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381239/primefaces-commandbutton-inside-orderlist-not-working) regarding the orderlist I got a new problem I don't understand.
Showing, Adding and Deleting data for my orderlist works pretty fine.

But how can I reorder the data inside the orderlist and store them.

If I use the standard feature of the orderlist, grab one item and pull it to another position. After I released the item at the desired position it jumps back to its old position and I get an index out of bound exception.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here:

technikers is just a plain ArrayList in my entity.

XML:

```
<h:panelGroup>

           <p:remoteCommand name="removeTechniker" actionListener="#{systemlandschaftRessourceHandler.removeTechnikerByRemoteCommand}"
                     out="technikersTable" update="@form"/>

           <p:orderList id="technikersTable"
                        value="#{systemlandschaftRessourceHandler.entity.technikers}"
                        var="_techniker" 
                        itemValue="#{_techniker}"
                        converter="#{entityConverter}"
                        controlsLocation="none"> 

                <f:facet name="caption">Techniker</f:facet> 

                <p:column>   
                    <p:commandButton id="deleteTechnikerFromListButton"
                                    styleClass="colButton"
                                    icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                    type="button"
                                    onclick="removeTechniker([{name:'id', value:'#{_techniker.id}'}]);"
                                    update="@form"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:75%;" id="outTech"> 
                   <p:outputLabel value="#{_techniker.verantwortlich.displayName}"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:orderList>

            <p:droppable id="technikerDrop" for="technikersTable" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource=":systemLandschaftTabView:sysObjektDetailPanelForm:userTable"> 
                    <p:ajax listener="#{systemlandschaftRessourceHandler.onDropTechniker}" update="@form" /> 
            </p:droppable> 
            </h:panelGroup>

           <h:panelGroup>
```

StackTrace:

```
    DEBUG 2013-10-16 11:13:53,899 [EntityManagerProducer] EntityManager geschlossen.
 INFO 2013-10-16 11:16:16,783 [context] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.primefaces.component.dnd.Droppable.queueEvent(Droppable.java:201)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:42)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:378)
    at org.primefaces.component.dnd.DroppableRenderer.decode(DroppableRenderer.java:32)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1181)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.visitTree(TabView.java:419)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.execute(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:95)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at de.company.sessioninfo.HttpSessionUserFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionUserFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by myself ;-)

solution was to specify the scope for p:droppable and the corresponding p:draggable

```
<p:droppable id="technikerDrop" for="technikersTable" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource=":systemLandschaftTabView:sysObjektDetailPanelForm:userTable" scope="userDraggable"> 
                <p:ajax listener="#{systemlandschaftRessourceHandler.onDropTechniker}" update="@form" /> 
        </p:droppable>
```